# GCC/G++ on Unbuntu makes a.exe that won't run: "Exec format error"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, linker, g++

I'm trying to get my working C/C++ code to compile with GCC/G++ on Ubuntu - apart from one weird bug and a few very minor differences from the MinGW GCC port, Intel and MSC compilers it compiled and linked OK.

Although it linked with no warnings and produced default a.exe the resulting executable refuses to run from the bash command line. I'm guessing this is some configuration error on my part. Both GCC and G++ were installed with their out of the box defaults. Below is the final link and execute step together with the result of gcc -v.

```
echo "Start link"
Start link
gcc  KeplerSolver.cpp -o KeplerSolver -O3 -Ofast -lm benchmark.o BM_shims.o BM_starter.o 
classic.o compilertests.o cuberoot.o deltas.o intel.o MyTrig.o opt_starter.o quartic.o 
PadeApprox.o solver.o starter.o stdafx.o tests.o verify.o  
martin@martin-virtual-machine:~/Documents/ks$ ./a.exe
bash: ./a.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

martin@martin-virtual-machine:~/Documents/ks$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' -- 
with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable- 
languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major- 
version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared -- 
enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable- 
threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu -- 
enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new -- 
enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie -- 
with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto -- 
enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 
--with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic - 
-enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp- 
nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without- 
cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu - 
-target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link- 
serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

I seem to have libraries in all the right places. The same code built OK with GCC using MinGW under Windows (it was just that some key floating point code was hardwired x87). Can someone spot what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You have the command `gcc  KeplerSolver.cpp -o KeplerSolver ...`, which outputs the program executable file `KeplerSolver`. Then you try to run `./a.exe`. Which is a different program (the `.exe` in its name indicates it was built for Windows, probably with MinGW as you mention that). What happens if you try to run `./KeplerSolver` instead?

Comment: Yes ! That works (at least it did once I got the capitalisation right!). Thankyou very much. The code came directly from the directory where GCC13 under MinGW resides. I'm still learning to use the GCC toolchain correctly and making daft mistakes on the way.

Comment: ***once I got the capitalisation right!*** Unlike MS Windows many linux filesystems will be case sensitive by default.

Answer (score 1):

The `-o` option indicates the output. You are compiling and saving the executable to `KeplerSolver`, not `a.exe`

```
gcc  KeplerSolver.cpp -o KeplerSolver ...
```

You need to run `./KeplerSolver`